# Android Activity within Activity using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have one activity which has 2 button clicking on which takes to second and third activity. Second activity has 2 buttons "return to main activity" and "click to third activity". When I click on to "return main activity button" it isn't returning to main activity screen But when I click on "go to 3rd activity" button it is going to third activity. 
Can someone help me why my "return main activity button" isn't working?

here is my code

```
main activity
{
package com.example.aditya.activitywithinactivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import static com.example.aditya.activitywithinactivity.R.id.start;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button bttn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        bttn1.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
        Button bttn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        bttn2.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.button1: {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            case R.id.button2: {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    };
}
```

SecondActivity.java

```
package com.example.aditya.activitywithinactivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        Button bttn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        bttn3.setOnClickListener(SecondActivity.this);
        Button bttn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        bttn4.setOnClickListener(SecondActivity.this);
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.button3: {
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                intent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                startActivity(intent2);
            }
            case R.id.button4: {
                Intent intent3 = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent3);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/myText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="buttonClicked"
        android:text="Click to go to Secondary Activity" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="buttonClicked"
        android:text="Click to go to Third Activity" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_second

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myText2" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="buttonClicked"
        android:text="Return to Main Activity"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="buttonClicked"
        android:text="Click to go to Third Activity"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Perhaps you should remove the onClick attribute from the xml as you are already implementing an onClickListener in your activities anyway?

Comment: Also, for the context of the intent you are having an issue with you put only "this" instead of SecondActivity.this.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.button3: {
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent2);
            break;
        }
        case R.id.button4: {
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent3);
           break;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: I just added this line intent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);

Comment: And added break statement too;

Comment: @mia ok good.if any answer help to you then upvote it or accept it

Answer (score 1):

You can call method `onBackPressed();` when return `MainActivity` button is clicked like this in `SecondActivity.java` and use `break` in `switch` statement

```
     public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {

                case R.id.button3: 
                      onBackPressed();
                      break;

                case R.id.button4: 
                    Intent intent3 = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent3);
                    break;

            }
        };
```

Comment: This will also misbehave. break or return is essential in such case.

Answer (score 1):

change in MainActivity

```
Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

The two lines code is in your source:

```
intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
intent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```

I want to know what do you want to do between two activities. The two sources follow can do it, but they are different.

```
    //Source code 1:
   Intent intent2 = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
   startActivity(intent2);

//Source code 2:
onBackPressed(); // or finish();
```

If use source code 1, the activities task will create another MainActivity object and put it to the top of task.

> MainActivity@obj1 | SecondActivity@obj1 ==>
>
> MainActivity@obj1 | SecondActivity@obj1 | MainActivity@obj2

If use source code 2, the activities tasks will remove SecondActivity object so that the MainActivity object at the top.

> MainActivity@obj1 | SecondActivity@obj1 ==>
>
> MainActivity@obj1

Answer (score -1):

There is no *break;* statement in your switch. It just continues to the next case step and therefore next activity. Also you can simply call *finish()* to end your current activity and go back - this will work better for your backstack. Anyway add *break;* after each case. Please check this [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) about *Switch statement*.

Comment: tried break and finish() both none of them is working.

Comment: You should use them anyway. Now I just saw the comment under your original question and completely agree - the onClicks are handled by your code and it should be removed from xml completely.

Comment: Thanks for the help.